# How to conditionally include sub automake configuration files

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, automake

I'm working in a project which uses automake to build the applications. We use one automake configuration file (Makefile.am) to build the application for multiple platforms. In this Makefile.am, platform specific sub automake configuration files (let's name them to Makefile.platform) are included like below:

```
include platform_A/Makefile.platform
include platform_B/Makefile.platform
...
include platform_X/Makefile.platform
```

What I want to do in a recent effort is to modify the Makefile.am to separate one of the platforms out while still keep it work for other platforms. I'm trying to do below

```
if PLATFORM_A
include platform_A/Makefile.platform
endif
include platform_B/Makefile.platform
...
include platform_X/Makefile.platform
```

But it seems that "include" takes effect before if/endif is evaluated, which means, if I remove "platform_A/Makefile.platform", automake will fail to parse Makefile.am successfully when I tried to build applications for other platforms (such as platform_B & platfrom_X)as it can't find "platform_A/Makefile.platform".

Could any expert here tell me how to conditionally include the external files in automake configuration file? The "conditionally" here means that if the condition is not fulfilled, the external file will not be included (imported) at all.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

depending on what your Makefile-snippets do, you could get away with:

```
if PLATFORM_A
-include platform_A/Makefile.platform
endif
```

in this case, the Makefile-snippets are simply included and not parsed by automake.
also note that if the `-include`d snippet does not exist, no error will be generated (the important part is the hyphen (`-`) prefixed to `include`)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do what you want.  You can flip the placement of the conditional around to accomplish the same thing:

**Makefile.am**

```
include platform_A/Makefile.platform
include platform_B/Makefile.platform
...
```

**platform_A/Makefile.platform**

```
if PLATFORM_A
...
endif
```

The description of the automake [include directive](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Include.html) says of included fragments:

> Makefile fragments included this way are always distributed because they are needed to rebuild Makefile.in.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for automake specifically but for GNU make at least ifeq/etc. works correctly to control conditional inclusion of makefiles.

```
$ more * | cat
::::::::::::::
Makefile
::::::::::::::
ifneq ($(ONE),)
include one.mk
endif
include two.mk
include both.mk

all: ;
::::::::::::::
both.mk
::::::::::::::
$(warning both.mk)
::::::::::::::
one.mk
::::::::::::::
$(warning one.mk)
::::::::::::::
two.mk
::::::::::::::
$(warning two.mk)
```

```
$ make
two.mk:1: two.mk
both.mk:1: both.mk
make: `all' is up to date.
```

```
$ make ONE=f
one.mk:1: one.mk
two.mk:1: two.mk
both.mk:1: both.mk
make: `all' is up to date.
```

Comment: I'm sure this does work.  The difference with automake is that `Makefile.am` is a sort of template to make the Makefile and the `include` directive is used in that context (when `configure` is run), and not when `make` is run.

Comment: Makes sense. According to the automake docs though a conditional there does do what you want (in not using that code) but it doesn't prevent the inclusion itself. Is there a reason you want to prevent the inclusion and not just the use of the content of that file? http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Include.html

Comment: The reason is I want to deliver the source code package of PLATFORM_B and make the package can be built & installed with "configure/make/make install" while excluding the source code of PLATFORM_A from the package. But I found if I remove all the code of PLATFORM_A (including Makefile.platform), make will fail on the source code package (configure can pass). Any idea?